How to Route Spring Cloud Gateway with Spring Authorization Server Downstream
This question is a follow up from https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/3636 issue, also a MCVE is attached to the issue.
what would be a recommended way of configuring it properly.

Please update the question to be self-contained.

When accessing http://dummy.traefik.me/login does not go through the security filter chain, if so, I think it can be done like this
 private ServerWebExchangeMatcher getSecurityMatcher() {
        return exchange -> {
            URI uri = exchange.getRequest().getURI();
            if (uri.getHost().equals("dummy.traefik.me")) {
                return ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.notMatch();
            }
            return ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.match();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .securityMatcher(getSecurityMatcher())
                .authorizeExchange(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        .anyExchange()
                        .authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .logout(withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }


This has security implications because the host can be influenced by headers in certain deployments based on configuration. Simply bypassing the filter chain may not be the best way to achieve the desired results (which need to be stated clearly in the question before answering, and at present it is just a link to a GitHub issue).
